# Visio Web Access Error

Tags: office-web-apps, visio, visio-services

I am responsible for a SharePoint 2013 farm that uses Standard CALs. As a result, we don't have a Visio service application provisioned.

I have a Visio document in a document library, and when I click the link I'd like it to simply open it in the Visio client application. Instead, it tries to open in the browser and gives the following error message:

> Sorry, we couldn't open your file using this feature. Visio Web Access is not available on this site.

I thought there might be a binding for it in Office Web Apps, but running `Get-SPWOPIBinding` I don't see anything for `.vsd` or `.vsdx` extensions.

How do I get it to skip trying to open in the browser and go directly to the client application?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the document library settings, there is an override available. Simply click on the Advanced Settings link and set the Opening Documents in the Browser section to Open in the client application.

Comment: But I only want it to do that for Visio documents.

Comment: is it an on prem farm? If so you could try to add the vsd mime type on the WFEs as application/octet-stream to force a download

Comment: It is an on prem farm. I tried your suggestion on both WFEs, did an iisreset, but still get the error message.